# can winston logger return the Object id of mongo db document

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I am curious to know that can `winston` return the object id of the document the collection in which it stored the error using `mongodb` . I tried to place a l.h.s variable but its giving as `undefined`. If not how can we achieve this?

```
winston = require('winston'),
mongod = require('winston-mongodb');
const moment = require('moment');

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    level: 'debug',
    timestamp: function () {
      return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
    },
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console({

        timestamp: function () {
          return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
        }
      }),
      new winston.Logger({
        level: 'debug',
        transports: [
          new(winston.transports.File)
          ({ filename: 'filepath' })
        ],
        timestamp: function () {
          return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
        }
      }),
      new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
              db : 'dbpath',
              collection : 'Logs',
                level : 'error',
                capped : true,
                timestamp: function () {
                  return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
                }

      })
    ]
  })


var objId = logger.error('error', 'Hello','5ad454648bef1f502db434dc', { req_id: "objid"});
console.log(objId);
```

Comment: Hi, please share some of your code, it's difficult to guess without seeing what you've tried to achieve

Comment: hi,I have placed the part of the code

Comment: Hi @PrabhatMishra did you find any suitable solution to your case?

Comment: Hi I am not sure but I think we changed our requirements.